# How to consume SOAP webservice in android

Tags: android, web-services, soap, android-ksoap2

How to consume a web service soap using ksoap2 library? I'm not sure which are these parameters: namescape, method_name, soapaction, url.

My web service is: http://www2.sentinelperu.com/ws/aws_datosfoto.aspx?wsdl
See Request and Result below.

[image: Request and Result]

This is my code,

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
request.addProperty("Usuario", "");
...
HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
```

Thanks, sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Is the answer working?

Answer (score 0):

namespace -> **targetNamespace** -> **AFPrivado**

method_name is name of the specified interface that you want to call

soapaction = namespace + "/" + method_name

url is

`http://www2.sentinelperu.com/ws/aws_datosfoto.aspx?wsdl`

or

`http://www2.sentinelperu.com/ws/aws_datosfoto.aspx`

Try both of them.Hope this can help.